# Background Image causing animated popViewController delay/lag

Tags: ios, swift, viewcontroller

I am getting a delay on animation when popping a view controller.

The reason I am getting the delay is because I have a background image.

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
       setBackgroundImage()
        
    }

@IBAction func navigationButton(_ sender: Any) {
        
        print("navigation button presssed")
        self.navigationController?.popViewController(animated: true)
    }

func setBackgroundImage() {

        let backgroundImage = UIImageView(frame: UIScreen.main.bounds)
        backgroundImage.image = UIImage(named: "RewardsBackgroundONLY")
        backgroundImage.contentMode = UIView.ContentMode.scaleAspectFill
        self.view.insertSubview(backgroundImage, at: 0)
    }
```

How do I prevent the delay from happening while setting the background image.

I also tried popping the view controller on the main thread, still doesnt work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Probably  your image is too large and the content mode `backgroundImage.contentMode = UIView.ContentMode.scaleAspectFill`  cause this behavior.

you have two ways to resolve this problem.

1. change the UIView.ContentMode  value and check if is ok for you. try  `scaleToFill`  or `scaleAspectFit`
2. resize image to fit on your app.

Comment: Weird, I've never had `scaleAspectFill` lag my app

Comment: @aheze  in fact this not cause lag, but it seems a lag. This is strange behavior in the navigation controller

Comment: @RamiresNascimento got it, weird.

Answer (score 0):

just set

```
clipsToBounds = true
```

it works for me